# Posting an array to database: Warning: mysqli_stmt::bind_param(): Number of elements in type definition string doesn't match

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

my php/mysql application generates an array to be inserted into a database. When I execute the insert query shown below, the insert does not take place, and these are the errors i get in the browser:

*Warning: mysqli_stmt::bind_param(): Number of elements in type definition string doesn't match number of bind variables in C:\wamp\www\useraccess\desktop\register.php on line 70

*Strict standards: Only variables should be passed by reference in....

Kindly offer suggestions to enable me resolve this.

**This is the array returned on Print_r():**

```
Array ( [lastname] => John [firstname] => Doe [email] => jdoe@yahoo.com [username] => terungwa [password] => encryptedpw)
```

**And this is the insert query code below:**

```
    // initialize flag
      $OK = false;;
// initialize prepared statement
    $stmt = $mysqli->stmt_init();
// set up escape_quote function for use in array_map
        function escape_quote($value)
        {
          if(($value))
              {
                 $value = "'$value'"; // add quotes to string values
              }                  
                return $value;
        }
    $sql = 'INSERT INTO members (';
    $sql .= implode(',', array_keys($filtered)); // build column list
    $sql .= ') VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)';
    if ($stmt->prepare($sql))
    {
        // bind parameters and execute statement
        $stmt->bind_param('sssss', implode(',', array_map('escape_quote', array_values($filtered))));
        // execute and get number of affected rows
        $stmt->execute();
        if ($stmt->affected_rows > 0)
        {
         $OK = true;
        }
     }
```

Comment: Why are you quoting values at all here? The point of bound parameters is to handle the separation of SQL and values so that you *don't* need to quote the values. This will end up putting (probably) unwanted quotes in your data. If you are later displaying the data in a context where it needs quoting, do the appropriate quoting there - not here.

Comment: @Andrew, your observation is noted, and I would have to read up on this again. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I resolved this issue by posting the array values directly rather than via the implode() function.

```
        $sql = 'INSERT INTO members (';
        $sql .= implode(',', array_keys($filtered)); // build column list
        $sql .= ') VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)';
        if ($stmt->prepare($sql))
        {
           // bind parameters and execute statement. insert array valuesis
           $stmt->bind_param('sssss', $filtered['lastname'], $filtered['firstname'], $filtered['email'], $filtered['username'], $hash);
           // execute and get number of affected rows
           $stmt->execute();
           if ($stmt->affected_rows > 0)
           {
             $OK = true;
           }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

[`implode()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) returns a string, so instead of 5 values, you are only sending 1: A string in which your real values are separated by commas.

Comment: @jerome, could you explain further, is implode not the appropriate function to use in this case?

Comment: @MichelMzer No, you need to bind the individual values, what you have now is something like `$stmt->bind_param('sssss', 'some,string,with,five,sections');`

Comment: @jerome echo implode(',', array_map('escape_quote', array_values($filtered))); returns 5 strings as shown below and not 1 string: 'john','doe','jdoe@yahoo.com','johndoe','encryptedpw'. Note i applied implode on array_map(), and not just the array values.

Comment: @MichelMzer Check the manual: `implode()` returns a string (1...) no matter what you feed it.

Answer (score 0):

implode() join array elements with a string, only 1.
You need 5 params on bind_param